# jQuery Hide if Div with same selector contains

Tags: jquery, contains

I have a series of divs/ sections 'section' and I want to hide any section in a series that contains specific text. So far i Have:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('section').each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(':contains("Textbox Section")')) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is it hides every 'section' rather than just the section containing the text if that text is present. How can I amend so that it ONLY applies to the section with the text in it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery('section:contains("Textbox Section")').hide();
```

---

No need of loop you can directly do this.

---

Updated after op's comment

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.section-textbox:contains("Textbox Section")').closest("section").hide();
});
```

Comment: this solved it for me:-

     <script>
     jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        jQuery('.section-textbox:contains("Textbox   Section")').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).closest("section").hide();
        });
    });
   </script>

As I need closest and as you say I don't need to loop how can I in turn hide the closest 'section'

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('section:contains("Textbox Section")').hide();
```